# Starting service automatically failed

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'm currently facing an strange issue.
I'm using debian squeeze under linux voyage on an alix.2d2 and I'm tring to launch an home made script at boot using init.d.

So to do that, I'm writing a simple script, putting it into /etc/init.d/ (/etc/init.d/linknx) and using update-rc.d configuring the boot.

```
update-rc.d linknx start 191 12345
```

Before rebooting, I'm testing the script using :

```
service linknx start
```

and it works nice.
When system reboots, script is not launched. I'm trying to change the boot config using update-rc.d

```
update-rc.d linknx defaults
```

Same issue.

So After that, I'm cleaning the boot config, and add two lines in the /etc/rc.local.

```
> sh -c "logger -p local0.notice [LAUNCHTEST] "rc.local invoking"
> service linknx start
```

The first line pass, but the second one fail.

Somebody can identify the problem ?

Thanks for your help !
regards

---

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e1
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          linknx
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $nocatsplash
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     false
# Short-Description: Start/stop linknx daemon
# Description: Simnet linknx daemond starter.
### END INIT INFO

now=$(date +"%F %k:%M:%S")
port=3671
ip=192.168.2.10
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
knx_config_file=/etc/linknx.xml
knx_write_file=/etc/linknx.xml

log_tag="[LINKNX]"
log_level="-p local0.notice"

case "$1" in
start)
    logger $log_level -t $log_tag -s "Starting linknx and eibd ..."
    ldconfig -l
    eibd -d -D -S -T -i ipt:$ip:$port
    linknx -d --config=$knx_config_file --write=$knx_write_file
    logger $log_level -t $log_tag -s "Done\n"
;;
stop)
;;
reload|restart|force-reload)
;;
test)
    logger $log_level -t $log_tag -s "[$now] - [TEST] - This is a simple test to check  behavior of the program ..."
;;
*)
   logger $log_level -t $log_tag -s "[$now] - [FATAL] - Unknow command, only available are start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload"
;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Might get more traction at http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
insserv linknx
```

And not

```
update-rc.d linknx defaults
```

As of Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), **update-rc.d** has been replaced with **insserv** (see [here](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot)). Why? Because 6.0 introduced a [new boot process](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#dependency-boot), for which you have the headers in place (the INIT INFO section at the top of the script).